# File changed on one branch changes on both branches

Tags: git, version-control

I'm experimenting with Git on my machine. I cloned some repository and added a new branch `my_branch`.

In this branch, I edited a row in one source file. I didn't `add` the change, and obviously didn't `commit` it.

I then switched again to `master`, and looked at the file on the disk. The change appeared there as well.

Two questions:

1- Should this be happening?

2- Does this mean that as a general rule, I should always `add` any change I did in a branch before switching to a different branch to do some different work (even if I don't want to commit my change yet)?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to 1: 
Yes. Like @bmargulies said, unless you do something about it, git keeps the change while you switch branches

Answer to 2:
Yes and No. You should *add and commit* it the changes if you want them on the branch you were working on. If not, the recommended method is to **stash** the changes, until you come back to the branch you were working on, and then *apply* or *pop* the stash.

Answer (score 1):

Your change is on *no* branches. If you edit a file, and don't do 'git add', let alone 'git commit', your change will just sit there unless you do something to get rid of it, like `git reset --hard HEAD` or `git checkout PATH`. If you went and made a clone of your repo you'd see that your change was not in it. If you used `git log` you'd see no sign of it.

Comment: I see. I now added the change on one branch, and not the other. The change still apears in the file even when I'm in the other branch. Why is this?

Comment: @poke I tried several times. After I commit a change in one branch, the change isn't reflected in the file when I'm in the other branch. However if I merely `add` a change in one branch, the change is visible in the file when I'm in the other branch too. Also, a change added in one branch can be committed in another branch. WTF?

Comment: `git add` does not affect the branch either. Adding a file adds it to the staging area, or index, where it’s prepared for committing. Once you committed something, a commit object is created and the branch is updated. Only then a change “belongs” to a branch.